# If $A$ is a nonzero $n\times n$ matrix, $B$ and $A+B$ have different eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to do this practice problem from my university:

If $A$ is a nonzero $n\times n$ complex matrix, prove that there exists an $n\times n$ matrix $B$ such that $B$ and $A+B$ have different eigenvalues.

My attempt so far: without loss of generality assume that $A$ is in Jordan canonical form. If no eigenvalues of $A$ are $0,$ then $B$ can be chosen to be a diagonal matrix.

However I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Can someone please give me some hints? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: when you say different eigenvalues you mean $A$ and $B$ don't share any eigenvalues?

Comment: I mean B and A+B don't share eigenvalues.

Comment: @nicomezi What do you mean spectrum? for matrices there is no difference between eigenvalues and spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

Right. If no eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$, you can even choose $B=0$.

So you can assume that some eigenvalues of $A$ are 0. We can assume that $A$ in fact consists of one Jordan block

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 &0... &0\\
                  0 & 0 & 1 &0... &0\\
    & ................\\
0& 0 &0 &0 ... &0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then let $B=E_{n,1}$, the matrix unit with $1$ in $(n,1)$-entry and zero everywhere else. Then the eigenvalues of $B$ are all zeroes but $A+B$ has determinant $\pm 1$ (depending on the parity of $n$), so none of the eigenvalues of $A$ is zero.

Comment: What if all the Jordan blocks of $A$ corresponding to $0$ are $1$ by $1.$

Comment: You are  of course aware of the fact that  the statement in the question is wrong if $A=0$.

Comment: Yes, but what if all Jordan blocks of $A$ corresponding to 0 are 1 by 1, but there can be other Jordan blocks corresponding to nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: In that case you can assume that the zero blocks  form the beginning of the main diagonal. You need to consider two cases. First when there is only one zero block of size 1 (it is easy). Second when there are several, say, k, zero blocks of size 1. In that case add some matrix units $E_{i,i+1}$, $i=1,...,k-1$ to make several zero blocks into one Jordan block and then add $E_{n,1}$ is the size of that block. The total matrix $B=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} E_{i,i+1}+E_{n,1}$ that you add will have all eigenvalues $0$.

Comment: uhh, why is the case of only one zero block easy? And in the second case the matrix B you add is the sum of many $E_{i,i+1}$ and $E_{k,1}$ which has nonzero eigenvalues though.

Comment: I fixed the comment. The case of one zero block can be treated the same way, and I am sure you can do it yourself.

Comment: If I understand the revised definition of $B$ correctly, $A+B$ can still have eigenvalue 0 though. Because it may have a row consists of all zeros.

Comment: Its determinant  is   not 0.